# selectbox click and send ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have `selectbox` and data send by ajax. this html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="kode_hanca" onchange="showModel(this)" name="id_vendor_detail[]" class="form-control vendor" required="">
                                    <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
                                    <script>
                                        $("select#kode_hanca").on("click", function () {
                                            $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php",
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                data: {type: "get_kode_hanca"}, //get_kode_hanca
                                                success: function (data) {
                                                    console.log(data);
                                                    var teks = "";
                                                    $.each(data.kode_hanca, function (index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
                                                        var id_vendor_detail = val.id_vendor_detail;
                                                        var kode_hanca = val.kode_hanca;

                                                        teks += "<option class='target_append' value='" + id_vendor_detail + "'>" + kode_hanca + "</option>";
                                                    });
                                                    $("#kode_hanca:last").append(teks);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </select>
```

data is convert to json and always dinamic. So every i select the `selectbox` data must load again. when i use `click` or `change` its not working to send ajax. how to solve it ?

Comment: Please **rearrange** your html code. Put the `<script>` outside your `<select>` element.

Comment: `<script>` tag should not come inside `<select>`. Please remove, and place that just before `</body>` tag. And try.

Comment: but please be careful if you mind request count to your server. when you open select a click event fires, after you even select an option or not, another click event fires again, when select is closing. It means, it makes two requests to your server when you open select and choose one. You should prevent this double requests in someway.

Comment: i think, in google-chrome (maybe other) the event click on selectbox is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

"select" tags cannot contain any other tags, it can only contain "option" tag.

try below code :-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="kode_hanca" onchange="showModel(this)" name="id_vendor_detail[]" class="form-control vendor" required="">
<option value="">- PILIH -</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#kode_hanca").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {type: "get_kode_hanca"}, //get_kode_hanca
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var teks = "";
               $.each(data.kode_hanca, function (index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
               var id_vendor_detail = val.id_vendor_detail;
               var kode_hanca = val.kode_hanca;

               teks += "<option class='target_append' value='" + id_vendor_detail + "'>" + kode_hanca + "</option>";
               });
                  $("#kode_hanca:last").append(teks);
             }
           });
        });
   </script>
```

You can also use "change", instead of "click."

**Edited:-**

Instead you can use below code:-

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select id="kode_hanca" onchange="myFunction();" name="id_vendor_detail[]" class="form-control vendor" required="">
        <option value="">- PILIH -</option>
        </select>

        <script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction()
{

showModel(this);

 $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   data: {type: "get_kode_hanca"}, //get_kode_hanca
                   success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                       var teks = "";
                       $.each(data.kode_hanca, function (index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
                       var id_vendor_detail = val.id_vendor_detail;
                       var kode_hanca = val.kode_hanca;

                       teks += "<option class='target_append' value='" + id_vendor_detail + "'>" + kode_hanca + "</option>";
                       });
                          $("#kode_hanca:last").append(teks);
                     }
                   });
}

           </script>
```

Comment: A little explanation won't hurt. :)

Comment: not work, how show alert like this : `<select name='select' onclick='alert('when click alert');'><option>- select -</option></select>`

Comment: you already have onchange declare with select, why you want onclick event? I would say call a function on onchange event and place ajax request and showModel() inside that function.

Comment: forget `onlclick()` . i forgot to erase it . so each i click selectbox, its recall data by ajax

Comment: `onchange()` just show other data when i select the one

Comment: It is showing an model box because of this line :- showModel(this);

Answer (score 0):

select dropdown you should try [onchange](https://api.jquery.com/change/) functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#kode_hanca").on("change", function () {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {type: "get_kode_hanca"}, //get_kode_hanca
           success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               var teks = "";
               $.each(data.kode_hanca, function (index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
               var id_vendor_detail = val.id_vendor_detail;
               var kode_hanca = val.kode_hanca;

               teks += "<option class='target_append' value='" + id_vendor_detail + "'>" + kode_hanca + "</option>";
               });
                  $("#kode_hanca:last").append(teks);
             }
           });
        });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeSelect() {
     $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "vendor_inout/vendor_inout_crud.php",
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {type: "get_kode_hanca"}, //get_kode_hanca
               success: function (data) {
                   console.log(data);
                   var teks = "";
                   $.each(data.kode_hanca, function (index, val) { //looping table detail bahan
                   var id_vendor_detail = val.id_vendor_detail;
                   var kode_hanca = val.kode_hanca;

                   teks += "<option class='target_append' value='" + id_vendor_detail + "'>" + kode_hanca + "</option>";
                   });
                      $("#kode_hanca:last").append(teks);
                 }
               });
}
</script>

<select id="kode_hanca" onClick="changeSelect(this.selectedIndex);" name="id_vendor_detail[]" class="target form-control vendor" required="">
<option value="">- PILIH -</option>
</select>
```